# Difference between Compute optimized instances and Accelerated computing instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and came across these two instances but I don't understand the need for the difference between them they seem the same can Anyone explain this

**Accelerated computing instances**

Accelerated computing instances use hardware accelerators, or coprocessors, to perform some functions more efficiently than is possible in software running on CPUs. Examples of these functions include floating-point number calculations, graphics processing, and data pattern matching.

In computing, a hardware accelerator is a component that can expedite data processing. Accelerated computing instances are ideal for workloads such as graphics applications, game streaming, and application streaming.

**Compute-optimized instances**

Compute-optimized instances are ideal for compute-bound applications that benefit from high-performance processors. Like general-purpose instances, you can use compute-optimized instances for workloads such as web, application, and gaming servers.

However, the difference is computed optimized applications are ideal for high-performance web servers, compute-intensive applications servers, and dedicated gaming servers. You can also use compute-optimized instances for batch processing workloads that require processing many transactions in a single group.

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 6):

The main difference between both of them is the hardware. Accelerated computing instances have GPUs which are accelerators whereas the compute optimized have good high performance processors. Though both of them provide high compute power, the way in which they are providing is different.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 1):

Compute Optimized instances are the instance designed for the applications that inturn gives the benefit as high compute power. These applications includes compute-intensive applications e.g. high-performance web servers, high-performance computing (HPC), distributed analytics, scientific modelling and ML inference

To know more about Compute Optimized instances you can refer this
[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compute-optimized-instances.html).

If you require high processing capability, you'll benefit from using accelerated computing instances, which provide access to hardware-based compute accelerators such as Graphics Processing Units (GPUs), Field Programmable Gate Arrays (FPGAs), or AWS Inferentia.

To know more about Accelerated Computing you can refer this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/accelerated-computing-instances.html).

Answer (score 0):

Both are very similar. In fact Accelerated computing could be considered a subcategory of compute optimized .

Compute optimized : Ideal for Compute intensive applications that require high performance. That is a very wide term and many tasks could fall under this category.

Accelerated computing : Those instances are ideal for compute intensive applications AND applications that require parallel processing .An example would be machine learning or high resolution graphics processors .Those instances may carry extra hardware not available in other instance types .